Can one hypervisor access the data from a virtual OS run by another hypervisor?
I'll try to clarify:

We have a computer with two OS installed, you can run either (that's easy).
Each OS has its own hypervisor installed, the hypervisors are the same.
When 0S_0 is being run, its Hypervisor_0 can run 10 virtual OS (OS_0_0, OS_0_1, ..., OS_0_9) at the same time.
Hypervisor_1 which is installed on the OS_1 is actually a copy of Hypervisor_0. OS_1 is a copy of OS_0 but just installed on a different hard drive partition or on another hard drive.

Now, the question:
When OS_1 is being run, can its Hypervisor_1 theoretically launch those 10 OS (OS_0_0, OS_0_1, ..., OS_0_9) which were run by Hypervisor_0 installed on OS_0?
Or just their copies but still work with the same data?
Or each hypervisor just creates its own virtual environment inaccessible externally?

What is the difference between launching an OS and launching a copy of the OS?  Why is this question relevant and useful to others?  We're looking to build an archive of knowledge that will be useful to others in the future, so it helps to provide context, motivation, background.

@D.W. they are identical, but installed on different hard drives or partitions. Like two independent OS.
